# Understanding connection pool work with Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, couchbase

I'm trying to implement connection pool to work with my service. Currently uWSGI is set up to run using 4 Processes and 2 threads each server for 3 servers. I'm trying to make connection pool for Couchbase based on [this example](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/examples/connection-pool.py).

What I don't understand is; if I implement this connection pool, will all the threads and processes within the same server be reusing the same pool? Say if I make the pool of size 8(4 processes x 2 threads), then I will have enough connection for that server?

As I understood that Flask reset its environment for each in-coming request. If so what's the point of making connection pool? Do I have to create connection pool before running uwsgi? How do I do that?

Is there a good example for non-postgresql connection pool for Flask out there?